# Removing requirement for buffer NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code which works in nodejs:

```
// Store Credentials
var userName = "username";
var sharedSecret = "secret";

// Build Header
var date = new Date();
var nonce = md5(Math.random());
var nonce_ts = date.toISOString().replace(/(\.\d\d\dZ)/ ,'Z');
var digest = (new Buffer(sha1(nonce + nonce_ts + sharedSecret)).toString('base64'));

alert(digest);
```

I understand both md5 and buffer don't form part of JS and are nodeJS. There is a regular JS buffer implementation but it seems very complex.

Is there a simpler way to still get the digest var created without having to use the buffer, as it doesn't seem hugely complicated.

Comment: Are you sure that your sharedSecret should be available for everyone? It looks like you should call a backend to generate the digest for your frontend

Comment: @ThomasKleßen Fair point. But it is just being run locally on my machine

Comment: Why don't you use another implementation of md5 and sha1 algorithms? They are pretty popular, I believe there are implementations which don't use `Buffer`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thank you. I'm a bit stuck though - if I used cyrptojs though, I cant see mention of buffer. What is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html
Specifically look at createHash and createHmac methods. After you created your hash you can use .digest('base64') to get the base64 formatted hash